# Change prefix to per-function sections generated by -ffunction-sections

Tags: gcc

If I have a function `foo()` and use `-ffunction-sections`, `gcc` will place `foo()` inside its own `.text.foo` section. Is it possible to change the prefix of `.text`? Such that I get `.customName.foo` instead of `text.foo`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and I solved it using the `section` attribute.

The following solution is the simplest but does not create a section for each function (as the `-ffunction-section` parameter allows to do)

```c
#define AT_FLASH_TEXT_SECTION(var) \
    __attribute__((section(".text.flash"))) var

AT_FLASH_TEXT_SECTION(int myFunction(float param1, long param2));
```

So the function `myFunction` will appear in the section `.text.flash`, but also all other functions that are declared using the macro `AT_FLASH_TEXT_SECTION`.

---

To get the desired behavior I modified the macro as follows:

```c
#define AT_FLASH_TEXT_SECTION_SYM(var, subsectionName) \
    __attribute__((section(".text.flash." #subsectionName))) var

AT_FLASH_TEXT_SECTION_SYM(int myNewFunction(float param1, long param2), myNewFunction);
```

This is the best solution I've found so far.
Unfortunately, it is error-prone: the function name must be repeated identically in the `subsectionName` parameter of the `AT_FLASH_TEXT_SECTION_SYM` macro. 
Furthermore, if two c modules contain two static functions with the same name, they will be emitted in the same section, going back to the previous problem.

I hope this helps, and maybe you can find a better solution starting from this.

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not seem possible. See `gcc/varasm.c` (I haven't run the debugger, but am fairly sure this is the code that computes section names.)

```
void
default_unique_section (tree decl, int reloc)
{
  [...]

  switch (categorize_decl_for_section (decl, reloc))
    {
    case SECCAT_TEXT:
      prefix = one_only ? ".t" : ".text";
      break;

  [...]

  name = IDENTIFIER_POINTER (id);
  name = targetm.strip_name_encoding (name);

  [...]

  string = ACONCAT ((linkonce, prefix, ".", name, NULL));

  set_decl_section_name (decl, string);
}
```

Besides, that might be a bad idea, as e.g. linker scripts treat sections based on their names (see `ld --verbose`). Something like `.text.customprefix.foo` might be a better choice, but I don't know why you want custom prefices.

---

As a workaround, you can assign sections manually with the section attribute.

```
'section ("SECTION-NAME")'
     Normally, the compiler places the code it generates in the 'text'
     section.  Sometimes, however, you need additional sections, or you
     need certain particular functions to appear in special sections.
     The 'section' attribute specifies that a function lives in a
     particular section.  For example, the declaration:

          extern void foobar (void) __attribute__ ((section ("bar")));

     puts the function 'foobar' in the 'bar' section.
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I can explain why I need to change the prefix: in baremetal firmware projects (running on microcontrollers with flash and little ram) it makes sense that initialization functions, and other functions executed only once, are in flash (normally slower) to free space in SRAM (normally faster) for functions that need maximum performance.

Comment: @mastupristi interesting to know, thanks. Doesn't the `section` funciton attribute solve it for you?

Comment: The `section` attribute partially helps, as I explained in my answer.